# WEB-XML File is showing Error Javaee_7.xsd Error

Tags: xml, eclipse, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2THcm.png)web-xml is created automatically when Dynamic web project is created but it is showing error Please suggest

'`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">`

Comment: Please add the `web.xml` formatted as _Code Sample_ and the error message as text to your question. What is in the _Problems_ view?

Comment: This issue should be fixed with https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/pull/779 . Please wait for a new release of Wild Web Developer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the language server. Check the Problems View for the Type of problem it's reporting, because this sounds just like https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1042 (since the default file contents haven't historically caused a validation error, because they're correct).